# Error with VBA Web Scrape

Tags: excel, vba, web, screen-scraping, libraries

I spent several hours researching this, couldn't find a solution.

I'm trying to do a relatively simple VBA web scrape on google. I'm currently hung up on inputting text into google's search box. There are three different routes I have seen, all of which cause errors.

One route is the following code

```
Dim aEXPLORER as InternetExplorer

Set aEXPLORER = New InternetExplorer

Do While aEXPLORER.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    Application.StatusBar = "Loading google..."
    DoEvents
Loop
```

At this point, the first route goes like this:

```
aEXPLORER.Document.Getelementbyid("idhere").value
```

The problem is after .document my intellisense stops working. If I continue to write the code anyway it errors out.

Route two - add at the top dim aHTML as  HTMLDocument

```
Set aHTML = aEXPLORER.document
aHTML.getElementById("idhere").value
```

This is marginally more successful as I get to the getelementbyID tag but my intellisense doesn't find a .value anywhere. I have a lot of other options like innertext, etc. But no .value like several people use in tutorials online.

I looked in my object libraries and I don't see a .value in my HTMLDocument library or my InternetExplorer library or my Excel library.

The problem has to be something with declaring a variable or an object or something of that nature. Why don't I ever get to a .value? This first method worked online for three different people showing tutorials, why isn't it working when I do it? How are they getting a Getelementbyid tag without setting up an HTML document at the top? For reference, this popular tutorial uses method one, "http://analystcave.com/web-scraping-tutorial/" about 75% of the way through the tutorial.

Thank you so much for being such helpful people. I'm at the end of my currently very limited rope.

---

Answer credit goes to Berco!

Problem 1: I was using the wrong ID identifier. Solution 1: Copy and Paste HTML code for each interaction point into VBA, comment it out, and copy/paste the identifier directly from that. This has several other benefits as well.

Problem 2: I was concerned with losing intellisense at .value. Solution 2: Not having intellisense does not mean the code won't work. It just means the code isn't set up with a dim/set. To solve for this one, you have to dim that item as an HTMLInput, which requires the Microsoft HTML Object Library reference to be checked. However, you may still use the .value etc even without intellisense as long as the HTML Object Library reference is checked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID of the googles searchbar is (id="lst-ib"). Try something like:

```
dim searchbar as object

set searchbar = aEXPLORER.Document.Getelementbyid("lst-ib")
searchbar.value = "I wanna google this"
```

Comment: Berco, just wanted to let you know I made it all the way from here to full automation of my administrative tasks at work. I appreciate your investment!

Answer (score 0):

Answer credit goes to Berco!

**Problem 1:**
I was using the wrong ID identifier.
**Solution 1:**
Copy and Paste HTML code for each interaction point into VBA, comment it out, and copy/paste the identifier directly from that. This has several other benefits as well.

**Problem 2:**
I was concerned with losing intellisense at .value.
**Solution 2:**
Not having intellisense does not mean the code won't work. It just means the code isn't set up with a dim/set. To solve for this one, you have to dim that item as an HTMLInput, which requires the Microsoft HTML Object Library reference to be checked. However, you may still use the .value etc even without intellisense as long as the HTML Object Library reference is checked.

Comment: Please use the edit link on your question to add additional information. The Post Answer button should be used only for complete answers to the question. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/14633202)

Comment: This is the answer to the questions I asked :)

Comment: To be sure, if it is the answer, it should be posted as an answer correct? Someone else just answered another question and I want to be sure to contribute back to the community by indicating that :) Thx!